# React State Hook initialised to [] still shows type as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, use-state

**Code:**

```
const [input, setInput] = useState('');
const [studentList, setStudentList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(studentList)
  console.log(studentList.type)
}, [studentList]);

return (
  <div id="add-students-input-div">
    <input
      type="text"
      id='add-students-input'
      value={input}
      placeholder='Enter a student to the database'
      onChange={(event) => {
        setInput(event.target.value)
      }}
    />
    <div id="add-students-button" onClick={() => {
      setStudentList([document.getElementById('add-students-input').value, ...studentList])
      setInput('')
     }}>
      <p>Add</p>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

**Problem:**
The print statement for `studentList` is returning the array but the print statement for `studentList.type` is undefined at all times, even after elements are added to the array.

How can I ensure that `studentList.type` returns `Array`.

Comment: Arrays don't have a `type` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_properties). Your state value is **always** an array, you don't need to check its type

Comment: Oh, cool thanks! Although, when I try to run ``studentList.map`` or ``studentList.forEach`` it says that they are not functions. How could I fix that?

Comment: Those functions should always be available. If you're having trouble using them, you should [edit] your question to show your code

Comment: Cool, I'll edit it. Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

studentList in your code will ever be an array, empty when you initialize the state. If you want to check if there is something in the array you have to use  `studentList.length`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, arrays do not have a `type` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_properties).

Your `studentList` state value is **always** an array; there is no need to check its type.

One thing you do appear to be doing incorrectly is updating `studentList` when you click your *button* (`<div>`). In short, you really shouldn't need to use DOM methods in React.

To update your array with the value from your `input` state, use this...

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  setStudentList((prev) => [input, ...prev]);
  setInput("");
};
```

and

```jsx
<div id="add-students-button" onClick={handleClick}>
  <p>Add</p>
</div>
```

See [useState - Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) for information on how I'm using `setStudentList()`

Answer (score 0):

Altough previous contributors solved your problem by eliminating it in other place, I would like to answer this:

> How can I ensure that studentList.type returns Array

If you want to make sure your variable is an array, you may use isArray() static method of Array:

```
Array.isArray(studentList) // returns true if array or false if not
```